# Why does the transmission oscillate when using a numerical dispersion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, greens-functions, dispersion

I understand that the transmission probability oscillates when the electron is considered to be a plane wave - this is because of the interference effects of these waves.
However, when a different dispersion is considered, for example, a numerical dispersion such as
$$E = Uo + 2t(1-cos(ka))$$ where $a$ is the mesh spacing, $Uo$ is the barrier potential and $t$ is the hopping parameter given by
$t^2 = \hbar^2/2m$, $m$ is the mass of the electron. In such a case, oscillations in the $T(E)$ curve is observed. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You still have interference in the hopping model. In fact, you can recover the continuum limit from it, so it is consistent.

Note that interference effect is a bit vague. You usually explain the energy dependence of transmission/reflection by talking about resonances and bound states. These also exist in the discrete case, so the same reasoning apply.

Hope this helps.